# Is there a way to set quotas to a user in a MinIO server?

Tags: minio

I have been using [MinIO](https://min.io/) as STaas for a few weeks now. I would like to know if there is a way to, given a created user, allow him/her to create buckets to **only** a previously assigned size. Let's say I want Nana (an user of my server) to be able to create buckets of up to 50GB, she can't buckets bigger than that.

I know it exist [AccessPolicies](https://blog.nikhilbhardwaj.in/2020/02/25/minio-bucket-policy/) and also [multitenancy](https://docs.min.io/docs/multi-tenant-minio-deployment-guide.html) in a minio deployment, but that's not what I'm asking for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not possible currently - but you can configure quotas on buckets after they have been created: https://docs.min.io/minio/baremetal/reference/minio-mc-admin/mc-admin-bucket-quota.html

The MinIO team is available on their public slack channel or by email to answer questions 24/7/365.

Comment: Thanks mate... That's what I tought